# Multiplying two multiindex dataframes with different but similar indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Please consider these two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['F', 'D']

s_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']],
                                  names=('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'))
s = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]], columns=cols, index=s_ind)
```

So s is:

```
                      F  D
cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4      
A    B    C    D     1  4
               E     2  5
               F     3  6
```

and...

```
ib_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A'], ['B'], ['C']], names=['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
ib = pd.DataFrame(data=[[7, 8]], columns=cols, index=ib_ind)
```

So ib is:

```
                 F  D
cat1 cat2 cat3      
A    B    C     7  8
```

Whether I multiply using axis 0 (shown) or 1 (not shown), I receive the same results. See here:

```
print(ib.mul(s, axis=0))
                      F   D
cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4        
A    B    C    D      7  32
               E     14  40
               F     21  48
```

Question: How do I perform the multiplication such that I receive this as an output?

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data=[[8*1,8*4], [0,0], [7*3,7*6]], columns=cols, index=s_ind))
                      F   D
cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4        
A    B    C    D      8  32
               E      0   0
               F     21  42
```

Note that the E row is 0 because there is no corresponding E column in ib to multiply. Alternatively, nans would be fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `s` and [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) `ib` with `level=1` on `axis=1` , then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it back and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `fill_value=0`

```
final = ib.mul(s.unstack(),level=1,axis=1).stack().reindex(s.index,fill_value=0)
# or: ib.mul(s.unstack('cat4'),level=1,axis=1).stack().reindex(s.index,fill_value=0)
```

Another way suggested by @piRSquared which involves reshaping just once (hence faster) is [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) the index to the index you want to match while multiplying then `stack` and `reindex` after multiplying:

```
s.mul(ib.rename_axis('cat4', axis=1).stack().reindex(s.index, fill_value=0), axis=0)
```

---

```
                        F     D
cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4            
A    B    C    D      8.0  32.0
               E      0.0   0.0
               F     21.0  42.0
```

Comment: I'd do it like this.  `s.mul(ib.rename_axis('cat4', axis=1).stack().reindex(s.index, fill_value=0), axis=0)`

Comment: @piRSquared: my solution is similar to yours : `s.mul(ib.stack().reindex(s.index, fill_value=0), axis=0)`  :)

Comment: @piRSquared ehh,,.. nice one, just once is the reshape then , i was thinking how to do that, may be got stuck with `unstack`  thank you :) Can I add it?

Comment: @anky_91 please do